# An explicit real sequence with certain properties

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove something and the proof relies on finding a real sequence $(r_n)$ such that:

- $r_n-r_{n+1}\ge \frac{1}{{(n+1)}^3}$    for each $n\in{\Bbb{N}}$
- $r_n\to0$ as $n\to{\infty}$

A natural way to construct such a sequence is by defining $(r_n)$ as a tail of some convergent series, but I want to find an explicit formula for $r_n$. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try $r_n = 1/n$?

Comment: Okay, after dealing with too many technical details, it seems I forgot the basic algebra today. Thank you

Comment: $r_n = 1/n^a$ works for all $1 \le a \le 2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct by changing $\geq$ for $=$ on the first condition and using the telescopic sum

$
r_{n}-r_{0} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} r_{k+1}-r_{k} = -\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)^{3}}.
$

Since the series is convergent, take $r_{0} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{3}}$, so you get $r_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.